# Hybrid app with Google Material Design

Tags: cross-platform, material-design, hybrid-mobile-app, angular-material, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I'm currently working on Android & iOS application with looks based on Google Material Design.

I've started off using using Cordova (Ionic + Ng-material), however the performance is poor particularly on Android devices. (more details by contributors here https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1177)

Is there any way of fixing the performance issue? If not is there any platform that would hep me develop the application (not necessairly hybrid, but cross-platform)?

I found that Xamarin / Appcelerator are capable of implementing Material front-end, but only on Android. I'd like to release the app on iOS with the same look.